# Need to check if a phonenumber in my contact is using whatapp or not

Tags: android, kotlin, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am creating a refer module where I will show a list of contact.when I click a particular number I need to open whatapp with prefilled message and image.Here I need to how to open that particular number message window with prefilled message

I tried to open that particular phonenumber chat window with prefilled image and message ,only window open no image is prefilled.I need like how Cred app show the share open,when click it launch whatapp with prefilled message.

Comment: There is no API to check whether the number is using WhatsApp or not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: On clicking the button I need to share both image and text message to a particular contact.for example if I click button it need to open the whatsapp chat with prefilled image and text message which I need to share.I know there is an API which support for message https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$number&text=$encodedMessage

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to send an image without any automation. Accordingly, in any case you will have to turn to unofficial api (ultramsg, whapi cloud, maytapi) or use official api (cloud itself from meta or providers like 360dialog, wati).
That said, I know that the official api has removed the ability to check if a contact has whatsapp itself or not. Unofficials win in this regard, but there are nuances there.

I do it like this in my project (I removed the private information from the code).

```
    
    const request = require('request');
    
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://gate.whapi.cloud/contacts?token=token',
      headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
      body: {blocking: 'wait', force_check: false, contacts: ['{{Recipient-WA-ID}}']},
      json: true
    };
    
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
    
      console.log(body);
    });
```